# перенос прав на папки и директории в другой лес

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell, active-directory, domain

есть  папка  x  в лесу one.local
в этой папке  разнообразные  подпапки  и фалы  с различными  правами безопасности
если в лесу two.local  создать  такую же папку  и  такие же группы,пользователей.
Как перенести  права  на папку?
icacls сохраняет  c sid-неудобно - нужно изменять sid - SamAccountName - SamAccountName В two.local - sid в two.local

Answer (score 0):

сам  себе отвечаю: есть  [subinacl](https://rdpdog.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/subinacl-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0/), должна налету  менять домен  в  acl,  но что-то не  получается. Зато  при  сохранении  прав  в файл и  замене  в  текстовом  файле  домена  и применении прав  из файлик все отрабатывает.